# Is there a torchvision 0.13.0 version available for ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pytorch, torchvision

I have used prior versions of torchvision in my docker images in the past however now I am trying to install torchvision version 0.13.0 onto the image (OS = ubuntu 18.04) however anytime my requirements.txt file hits the line

```
torchvision==0.13.0
```

I get this error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.13.0

I installed and used the same version on google colabs so I know the it is available, I just need a way to get it onto ubuntu via docker.
I also tried installing the same version directly on a ubuntu 18.04 VM (same error) so I think it is an issue with ubuntu.

I have tried

- adding line pip install torchvision==0.13.0 to requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing torchvision via "RUN" command in dockerfile.

Adding the following lines in the dockerfile fixed the issue:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get clean 

# Install miniconda
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda

# Put conda in path so we can use conda activate
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH

# Install torchvision
RUN conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```